# items not rendering in django-template

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am just trying to render a query but it's not showing in the template for one view and it's showing up in another i am not sure why.

the template :

```
<div class="dropdown">
        <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">{{vessel_id.name}}</button>
        <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
            {%for vessel in vessel%}
            <a href="{% url 'maintenance:home' pk=vessel.id %}">{{vessel.name}}</a>
            {%endfor%}
        </div>
    </div>
```

here in this view the {{vessel.name}} is not working and doesn't render any drop down vessels
view.py

```
def update_component(request, pk):
    vessel_id = Vessel.objects.get(id=pk)
    # get the id of this specfic component
    component_id = Component.objects.get(id=pk)
    # get the vessel of this specfic component
    component_vessel = component_id.vessel
    # fetch all components of this specfic vessel
    component = component_vessel.components.all()

    vessel = Vessel.objects.all()
    form = ComponentModelForm(instance=component_id)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'form-update' in request.POST:
        form = ComponentModelForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=component_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'form-delete' in request.POST:
        component_id.delete()
        return redirect('/maintenance')
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': form,
        'component_id': component_id,
        'vessel': vessel,
        "component_vessel":component_vessel,
        'vessel_id':vessel_id
    }
    return render(request, 'update_component.html', context)
```

while this view is working just fine for the same template
view.py:

```
def index(request, pk):
    vessel_id = Vessel.objects.get(id=pk)
    vessel = Vessel.objects.all()
    component = vessel_id.components.all()
    component_id = Component.objects.get(id=1)
    form = ComponentModelForm(instance=component_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComponentModelForm(
            request.POST, request.FILES, instance=component_id)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': form,
        'vessel': vessel,
        "vessel_id": vessel_id
    }
    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your `object` name different in your `html` and try again.

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">{{vessel_id.name}}</button>
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
        {% for vessel_obj in vessel %}
        <a href="{% url 'maintenance:home' pk=vessel_obj.id %}">{{vessel_obj.name}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```